# reset AtomicInteger to zero if it is going to overflow in thread safe way

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, thread-safety

I have a `AtomicInteger` that is being incremented by multiple threads.

I want to reset to zero if that `AtomicInteger` overflows but in an atomic way. I want to make sure `counter` variable value is always positive so as soon as `clientCounter` overflow or going to overflow, I will reset that AtomicInteger to zero. I came up with below code but I am not sure is it thread safe because I am doing addition to check and reset. Is there any better way to do this?

```
  private static final AtomicInteger clientCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);

  // called by multiple threads
  public static int getCounter() {
    final int counter = clientCounter.incrementAndGet();

    // reset "clientCounter" to zero as soon as it overflow
    // basically I don't want "counter" value should be negative if it overflow
    // is below thread safe?
    if (counter + 1 < 0) {
      clientCounter.set(0);
    }

    if (counter % SIZE == 0) {
        // save counter in database
    }

    return counter;
  }
```

**Update:**

Below is my method and I am using `newCounter` value to save in database as well. And the line where I am saving in database, it is asking to make `newCounter` as final variable and I can't make `newCounter` as final variable here. How to fix this now?

```
  public static int getCounter() {
    int counter;
    int newCounter;
    do {
        counter = clientCounter.get();
        newCounter = counter < Integer.MAX_VALUE ? counter + 1 : 1;
    } while (!clientCounter.compareAndSet(counter, newCounter));

    if (newCounter % SIZE == 0) {
      Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          // this is asking "newCounter" to make final
          DBClient.getInstance().save(newCounter);
        }
      });
    }

    return newCounter;
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you need `compareAndSet` for this.

```
int counter;
int newCounter;
do {
    counter = clientCounter.get();
    newCounter = counter < Integer.MAX_VALUE ? counter + 1 : 1;
} while (!clientCounter.compareAndSet(counter, newCounter));
return newCounter;
```

Comment: Could not two interleaving threads both return the same "newCounter" with your example.

Comment: I edited my question. My if check was wrong earlier. Basically I need to reset `clientCounter` to zero if it is going to overflow so that `counter` value is always positive.

Comment: I do not believe the above is solves the problem. You will need to put a synchronized block around the whole thing to prevent it returning the same value to two interleaving threads.

Comment: @bhspencer no, the promise of compareAndSet guarantees that in one thread, the loop continues.

Comment: @flash I get that you don't want to return negative numbers, but is zero ok?

Comment: OK but why is this better than simply putting a synchronized block around a normal integer.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat for example in a normal scenario `clientCounter` is initialize to zero and `incrementAndGet` on it gives value as 1 so thats how I want to be. if I reset `clientCounter` to zero then the value to counter variable should be 1 and then  followed be `2, 3, ...` and so on..

Comment: @flash I think this code does that. If it doesn't, it would help to see the equivalent implementation with synchronized so that I understand exactly what I'm aiming at.

Comment: @bhspencer code above uses `AtomicInteger.compareAndSet()` which is executed atomically. So even if two threads get the same value for `newCounter` only one of them will actually set new value in `AtomicInteger`. Second thread will get `false` from `clientCounter.compareAndSet(counter, newCounter)` and will start new iteration. And this is better then `synchronized` in case of small contention because it avoids context switching and rescheduling of threads

Comment: @bhspencer Because `synchronized` is expensive, and loop is very short, so probability of collision is small, so a tight loop that almost never fires is less expensive than the overhead of `synchronized`. The tight loop only affects performance on collision, but `synchronized` would affect performance on *every* increment.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I updated my question just now with details at the end. I am saving value of newCounter to db as well in my original code and it is asking to make `newCounter` as final but I can't make it now with the code suggestion you gave. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @flash, there are several solutions to this `final` problem. One is to wrap the whole loop into a named method and then use something like `final int newCounter = incrementCounterImp();`. Another solution is to introduce one more variable _after_ the loop `final int finalCounter = newCounter;`

Comment: @bhspencer, on many hardware platforms, the implementation of `clientCounter.compareAndSet(counter, newCounter)` is a single, user-mode instruction.  Much faster than making a system call to lock a mutex.

Answer (score 1):

The OP is a genuine use-case, but surprisingly there is little info out there on this. The counter needs to wrap back to 0 when it reaches a given MAX_COUNT. You could do this with the below

```
synchronized(clientCounter) {
  clientCounter.compareAndSet(MAX_COUNT, 0);
  return clientCounter.getAndIncrement();
}
```

It is important to synchronize the two statements above into one block to make sure only one thread at a time increments the counter so that the counter never gets incremented beyond the MAX_COUNT.

We can also achieve the same with the built-in getAndAccumulate function

```
return clientCounter.getAndAccumulate(MAX_COUNT, (current, maxCount) -> current < MAX_COUNT ? ++current : 0)
```

Comment: Try execute in multiple threads with a short sleep between the set and get: you will see the counter getting incremented past the MAX_COUNT

Comment: I see. But if you use `synchronized`, then you don't need AtomicInteger, is it right?

Comment: The correct solution for the OP's requirement could be as simple as
```Integer.MAX_VALUE & al.getAndIncrement();```
My answer was for a more general case of a given MAX_COUNT that is smaller than Integer.MAX_VALUE. The ```getAndAccumulate``` function was not available prior to Java 8, so the need for that ```synchronized```